# Flutter_Translate: Method invocation is not a constant expression

Tags: flutter

How can fix this issue. Thanks so much.

```
import 'package:flutter_translate/flutter_translate.dart';

class TabViewerPopupMenuActions {
  static const String NEW_TAB = translate(
      'options.new_tab'); //ERROR: Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.

  static const List<String> choices = <String>[
    NEW_TAB
  ];
}
```

i try remove const

```
class TabViewerPopupMenuActions {
  static String NEW_TAB = translate(
      'options.new_tab'); 
  static List<String> choices = <String>[
    NEW_TAB
  ];
}
```

but switch-case error

```
 switch (choice) {
   case TabViewerPopupMenuActions.NEW_TAB
```

> ERROR: Case expressions must be constant

Comment: What is the choice variable?

Comment: choice: NEW_TAB, SETTINGS, NEW_INCOGNITO